# Помогите решить задачу! Платная лестница

Tags: python, динамические-массивы

Мальчик подошел к платной лестнице. Чтобы наступить на любую ступеньку, нужно заплатить указанную на ней сумму. Мальчик умеет перешагивать на следующую ступеньку, либо перепрыгивать через ступеньку. Требуется узнать, какая наименьшая сумма понадобится мальчику, чтобы добраться до верхней ступеньки.

Входные данные:

В первой строке входного файла вводится одно натуральное число N≤100 — количество ступенек.
В следующей строке вводятся N натуральных чисел, не превосходящих 100 — стоимость каждой ступеньки (снизу вверх).

Выходные данные:

Выведите одно число — наименьшую возможную стоимость прохода по лесенке.
У меня получился такой код:

```py
n = int(input())
a = []
count = 0
a=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))[:n]
while len(a) != 0:
    if len(a) == 1:
        count += a[0]
        print(count)
        a.pop(0)
    else:
        b = min(a[0], a[1])
        count += b
        if b == a[0]:
            a.pop(0)
        else:
            a.pop(0)
            a.pop(0)
```

Но программма ничего не выводит. Где ошибка?

Comment: А как Вы пытались решить?

Comment: чесно говоря никак. динамические массивы у меня вообще не заходят, а тут нам дали задачи, сказали "решайте", и всё....... тупик......

Comment: ну значит все. не ваш путь. задумайтесь о смене направления учёбы.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что данная задачка очень похожа на вот эту - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1298033/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%83/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамические массивы здесь ни при чём

```
a = [5,8,9,2,7,14,6,3]
for i in range(len(a)-3,-1,-1):
    a[i]+=min(a[i+1],a[i+2])#перешагивать на следующую,либо перепрыгивать через ступеньку
print(min(a[0],a[1]))
```